# Word for the day you have spent half of your life with someone

Tags: single-word-requests

My wife and I are approaching the point in our lives where we have been together for longer than we haven't. 
I was born in 81, she in 82 and we got together in 2000. I'm planning to celebrate the exact date this happens for each of us.

Is there a word for the landmark date where days prior to the start of a relationship becomes less than days in the relationship?

Comment: If you discover what it is, please try and devise an equivalent for the day on which you have spent twice as long together as you have not. I calculate that my wife passed that point on 11 July last year. But being 3.5 years older I've got a further more than 6 years to go.

Comment: Ironically, for me that day might be today.

Comment: _Half Life Anniversary_. It is used in this article also: https://fadedginger.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/anniversary-2012/amp/

Comment: @ermanen if you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Phil: It is more of a nonce phrase but it is self-explanatory. It can have different meanings in different contexts also. I don't mind if you put it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, *half-life anniversary* can be used.